# Spring boot OAuth 2 gives "Unauthorized Error"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

Project location: https://github.com/nydiarra/springboot-jwt

I am using the above project to get done OAuth authentication with Spring boot. But while calling "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token", throws "Unauthorized" error after I have upgraded "spring-boot-starter-parent" version into "2.0.0.RELEASE". How can I resolve this?

While cloning the project, "spring-boot-starter-parent" version was "1.5.3.RELEASE" It is working fine meaning that I can authenticate.
After I changed the version, "Unauthorized" errors are throwing.

Comment: Probably related to the new password storage format... https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#pe-dpe-format

Comment: can you give security configuration code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are using shapassword encoder, with encoding strength 256. encode your secret and add it in security.jwt.client-secret of application.properties

and replace below dependency in your pom

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
<version>2.0.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This should work fine